# mintty with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey, mintty

I'm using a simple AHK script to move windows around:

```
NumpadEnd::
        WinMove,A,, 50,730,1000,314
return
```

This works great on everything, except mintty. It just completely ignores it. I have tried changing the keybind with no succes. Does anyone have any experience with this problem or knows how to get mintty to work with AHK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `WinMove,A,, 50,730,1000,314` should only work with windows with a WinTitle `A`.

I think `WinMove,,, 50,730,1000,314` OR `WinMove,50,730,1000,314`  will work for you.